# Map not showing up with folium.Map() v0.10.0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium, choropleth

Choropleth is showing but the background map is just grey. using folium 0.10.0 in jupyter

Apparently there used to be a _build_map() function to do this that was removed from folium and folium.Map() seems to work for people now but not in my case.
I also tried the .display(Map) without any results.

```
SF_map = folium.Map(location=SF_coordinates, tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=12)

display(SF_map)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=SF_geo,
    name='Choropleth',
    data=df_incidents,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime Incidents by Neighborhood'    
).add_to(SF_map)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(SF_map)

SF_map
```

I expected to have a choropleth layer ontop of a visable map, but its the choropleth layer upon grey. when calling the map by itself before adding the choropleth the + and - zoom buttons appear and seem to function once you get to the limits of the zoom, but its all grey. No error messages are returned.

Comment: I believe the example screenshot in the project assignment uses `tiles='OpenStreetMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely map is not appearing (displayed as a gray) since tiles could not be loaded, in that case the following errors are displayed in console:

[image]

Even though `Mapbox Bright` is [listed among default tilesets](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/cc5e8d9e1ac49ceb2854e13aa58bd4c347a07225/folium/folium.py#L77) in folium:

```
- "OpenStreetMap"
- "Mapbox Bright" (Limited levels of zoom for free tiles)
- "Mapbox Control Room" (Limited levels of zoom for free tiles)
- "Stamen" (Terrain, Toner, and Watercolor)
- "Cloudmade" (Must pass API key)
- "Mapbox" (Must pass API key)
- "CartoDB" (positron and dark_matter)
```

it appears `Mapbox Bright` tileset is no longer available (the similar issue [has been reported here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1177))

When switching to `OpenStreetMap` tileset:

```
coordinates = [37.7577627,-122.4726194]
map = folium.Map(location=coordinates, tiles='OpenStreetMap',  zoom_start=12)

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data='https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson' ,
    name='choropleth',
    data=df_incidents,
    columns = ['PdDistrict','IncidntNum'],
    key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',
    fill_color='YlOrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.6,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crime in San Francisco'
).add_to(map)

map
```

choropleth layer along with a map is getting displayed as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do like this,

```
import geocoder
import folium

location = geocoder.ip("me")
real_location = location.latlng
map = folium.Map(location=real_location, zoom_start=12)
map.save(outfile="map.html")
```

and also don't forget to save your code(.py) file.

always write "outfile=" in saving the map function